# List - take elements with equal name

Tags: python, list, extract, combining-marks

Having a List like this:

```
[utc1_1.tga, utc1_2.tga, utc1_3.tga, utc1_4.tga,
 utc2_1.tga, utc2_2.tga, utc2_3.tga, utc2_4.tga,
 utc3_1.tga, utc3_2.tga, utc3_3.tga, utc3_4.tga,..]
```

I separated with this:

```
images = list(sorted([int(name.split('_')[0]) for name in directory_files]))
```

only timestamp names remain:

```
[utc1, utc1, utc1, utc1, utc2, utc2, utc2, utc2, utc3, utc3,...]
```

basically this list of images are numpy array. I would like to add the arrays with the equal timestamp.

You can check actual files at this [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QNs5ZqOTZZpERmIukm8y5jgskqT0ch2O?usp=share_link)

```
import cv2
from numpy import asarray
from multiprocessing import Process
import glob
from PIL import Image


images = glob.glob(f"{directory_files}*.tga")
for img_name in images:
  with open(img_name, 'rb') as ldr:
    print(img_name)
    image = Image.open(ldr)
    data = asarray(image)
    print(data.shape)


#images = list(sorted([int(name.split('_')[0]) for name in directory_files]))
#print(images)

#same_utc_arrays = 
#np.sum(same_utc_arrays)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got it.

But if you want to separate them by timestamp. I would map them into a dict using timestamp as key.

Basically you would need to grab all different timestamp then start a dict, after that you could separate them by pushing to the respective timestamp key from the dict.

Comment: Answers must actually answer the question. If you demonstrate, that's even better. A proposed approach is not an answer. This is a problem with most of your answers.